# how to record video on server instead of browser using record rtc

Tags: javascript, easyrtc

Im building an application in which i have successfully implemented video chat functionality using easyrtc. Now what i want to do is record that video. I have done that as well by reading tutorials over the internet.

But I'm able to record the video at client side(on browser). while i want to record it on server directly. because in this way, my browser get hang and stops responding due to the size of video.

Is there any possible way to save it directly on server or it can be sent to server simultaneously when it recorded.

any help would be appreciated.

thanks
Neeraj

Comment: if you can save it on the client then presumably you can have the client send the data to your server. as long as data is reachable to a client, it can be reachable to a server.

Comment: I know it is reachable, but as i said it makes the browser too heavyweight to respond. i want some mechanism to save it directly on server. i heard about the binaryjs module which gives this functionality. Now looking forward any suggestion to implement into my code.

anyway thanks for paying attention

Comment: maybe there's a faster way of sending the data than what you're using; ex window.URL instead of FileReader, or maybe you can use a worker and transferable objects in messages for uploading to keep the main thread responsive.